# Signpost not working

Tags: java, servlets, oauth, signpost

I use Tomcat7 with Eclipse.

Steps I've done:

1. Imported commons-codec-1.10.jar as External JAR
2. Imported signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar as External JAR
3. Imported signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar as External JAR
4. Checked them in "Order and Export"

Imports:

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
```

Code:

```
OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer("Hidden", "Hidden");
consumer.setTokenWithSecret("Hidden", "Hidden");

url = new URL("...");
HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
try {
            consumer.sign(c);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException
                | OAuthExpectationFailedException
                | OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));
```

But when I try to start the Servlet, I get this:

```
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Webapp0' did not find a matching property.
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Webapp1' did not find a matching property.
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Webapp2' did not find a matching property.
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Webapp3' did not find a matching property.
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNUNG: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Webapp4' did not find a matching property.
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Windows 7
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            6.1
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Boxberger\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Boxberger\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Boxberger\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.57-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 330 ms
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Catalina
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Immofy]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Immofy]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth/signpost/exception/OAuthMessageSignerException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 20 more

Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SCHWERWIEGEND: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SCHWERWIEGEND: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMATION: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMATION: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFORMATION: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMATION: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 10, 2015 12:25:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMATION: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

When I start the Servlet without the OAuth imports it works great.
Where is my failure?